# Style.xml display error

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Whenever I am creating a new project in Android Studio it will show the helloWorld print, but it shows nothing unless I go to styles.xml and change

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

to

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

I have to do this every time, How should i solve this problem permanently?

Answer (score 0):

Because of the new library version.

You can change the appcompat version by using this code in your dependencies

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
```